# Conda list help: Windows activate script route produces blank response

Tags: windows, conda

I'd like to have a script very much like this:

```
@echo off    
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\ProgramData\miniconda3\Scripts
%windir%\System32\cmd.exe "/K" C:\ProgramData\miniconda3\Scripts\activate.bat myenv
```

That I can chuck into a directory, and double click to get a interactive conda environment going there, already in 'myenv'. The above mostly works, bringing up a prompt in that environment that you can run python from.

But when you type "conda list" or "conda env list" into that prompt it returns nothing. Starting up the default conda windows shortcut, then "conda activate myenv" followed by either of those commands actually lists stuff. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You need to follow these steps to solve the problem :

- Use the `call` Command : When running a script from another script, it is useful to use the `call` command. This ensures that the environment variables set in the called script are preserved in the calling script.
- The Activation of Conda Environment : When activating the `conda` environment, check that it has been correctly activated with the `conda` activate command.

And modify the script as follow :

```bash
@echo off
call :activate_conda_environment
goto :eof

:activate_conda_environment
set "CONDA_BASE=C:\ProgramData\miniconda3"
call "%CONDA_BASE%\Scripts\activate.bat" %CONDA_BASE% && conda activate myenv
goto :eof
```

Save the script with the extension `.bat` and place it in the directory where you want to activate the `conda` environment. Double-clicking on this batch script will activate the desired environment and allow you to execute commands such as `conda` sheet and `conda` env sheet.

Remember to replace `"C:\ProgramData\miniconda3"` with the actual path to your `Miniconda` installation.

This approach uses the `call` command to start the Conda environment and ensure that changes to environment variables are retained after the script is executed. This solves the problem and allows interaction with the Conda environment.